# $y''-y=e^x$ initial conditions $y(0)=0$, $y'(0) = \frac{3}{2}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-explanation, initial-value-problems

This is the solution to the reference:

[image]

How did the blue line come out, or set it out?
This is really hard for me to think about, what is the general method?

Comment: thank you for edit @cmk

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $e^x$ is a solution of $y''-y=0$, then a particular solution has the form
$$ y_p=Axe^x. $$
Putting this into the equation gives $A=\frac12$. Let the general solution be
$$ y=C_1e^x+C_2e^{-x}+\frac12xe^x. $$
Then use the initial condition to solve $C_1,C_2$. You can try yourself.

Comment: thank you very much. if

Comment: You are welcome.

Comment: and if $2e^x$ or $2xe^x$ is a solution what is $$ y_p= $$?

Comment: if $y''-3y'+2y=2xe^x$ may be a solution，$$ y_p?$$

Comment: Since $e^x$ is a solution of $y''-3y'+2y=0$, so set $y_p=(Ax^2+Bx)e^x$.

Comment: thanks for your patience .you are really very helpful to help me, thank you again.

Comment: I extend my compliments and congratulations of the user.